# Site usage analytics

Tags: analytics

When trying to understand how site usage analytics work I can see the same document with different extensions. I see the document as a PDF (which it is) and as an aspx. Both have unique visitors. However one and the same document has more visitors as an aspx than it has as the PDF.
Could someone please tell me what the difference is and how many unique visitors the document really had?
Thank you.

Comment: could you explain how the pdf is same as an aspx? The aspx page is embedding the pdf?

Comment: I meant it is the same name (as it comes from the same document). How can the aspx page show more views than the pdf please?

Comment: There could be many reason?  E.g. search result show aspx on higher rank so most uaers click on it?

Comment: Thank you for your help Mark L. But did the people that clicked on the aspx also actually read the document I am wondering? I do not know which number is the real number of original users actually reading the document. As it could either be quite a lot of people or only a few. And we have to decide if traffic is substantial enough to continue providing the documents.

Comment: I couldn't understand why click on the aspx also read the pdf? The aspx page is embedding the pdf?

Comment: Mark L: so the aspx analytics show the real number of views a document had?

Comment: if user request https://xxxxx/xxx/xxx.pdf then the count will goto pdf. If user request https://xxxxx/xxx/xx.aspx then the count goto aspx.

Comment: Thank you Mark L.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to consolidate the views for this PDF.

If your company has a self-hosted web analytics tool that reads web server access logs, you can use a filter to consolidate the views and generate a Visit / Visitor view count for the PDF.